# How to upgrade the Spring Framework version from 4.0.5.RELEASE to 5.3.20

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, upgrade, spring-framework-beans

I want to upgrade the Spring Framework version from 4.0.5.RELEASE to 5.3.20 using Maven.

The versions in my pom.xml is

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springframework-security-version>3.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-security-version>
        <org.apache.tiles-version>3.0.4</org.apache.tiles-version>
        <org.hibernate-version>4.2.15.Final</org.hibernate-version><!-- 4.3.5.Final -->
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.7</org.slf4j-version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
</properties>
```

Can anybody help me in which all files I have to make changes.
Do I need to change other versions also in pom.xml to make it compatible with the new Spring version?

PS - I am new to Spring Framework. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Take small steps don't jump 7 versions at once. Yes you need to modify other things as well as the minimal supported versions have been increased as well. So take small steps, one version, one framework at a time. Read the documentation on changes in the different versions and adapt your code/configuration.

Comment: I am facing same situation, also would like to know the answer. Have you been able to solve this?